# Get Twitter Followers number

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, twitter

I wan to get twitter followers numbers for any user from the any of twitter api. The twitter api 1 allow for this but it does not available any more.

```
 so now https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show
```

I can get just for user

any one can help me :)

Comment: Did  you tried https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI


https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Version 1.1 you'll have to create a Twitter app and then use the oauth_token, oauth_token_secret ,oauth_consumer_key ,oauth_consumer_secret values to call the REST API.

Refer to following articles. They explain with code how to connect to Twitter and get the required details out.

http://aspxdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2013/06/twitter-api-11-example-on-c-asp-dot-net.html

https://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/

Cheers!